# Who first devised the vowel-consonant designations in the taxonomy of syllogisms? (e.g. Barbara, Celarent, Darii, Ferio, etc.)

Tags: logic, history-of-philosophy

In the history of philosophy & logic there is a taxonomy of syllogisms designated by name. William of Sherwood and Peter of Spain write of a mnemonic to help medieval students of logic memorize the syllogisms:

> Barbara celarent darii ferio baralipton
>   Celantes dabitis fapesmo frisesomorum;
>   Cesare campestres festino baroco; darapti
>   Felapton disamis datisi bocardo ferison.

Vowels & particular consonants have particular meaning.

- a – universalis affirmativa (i.e. **a**ffirmo)
- e – universalis negativa (i.e. n**e**go)
- i – particularis affirmativa (i.e. aff**i**rmo)
- o – particularis negativa (i.e. neg**o**)
- s – conversio **s**implex.
- p – conversio **p**er accidens.
- c – reductio ad **c**ontradictionem
- m – **m**etathesis (in Petrus Hispanus, conversio per contrapositionem?).
- B – reductio ad Modus **B**arbara.
- C – reductio ad Modus **C**elarent.
- D – reductio ad Modus **D**arii.
- F – reductio ad Modus **F**erio.

Whom first devised the vowel-consonant designations in the taxonomy of syllogisms?

(A link to an article describing the context of logicians naming syllogisms mnemonically: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-syllogism/)

Comment: A related question which does not contain the answer http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/17935/how-do-i-use-the-barbara-celarent-etc-mnemonic

Answer (score 2):

The source is [Medieval Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-syllogism/).

According to :

- Joseph Maria Bochenski, [A History of Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=QXoIAQAAIAAJ) (1961), §32:

> L. Minio-Paluello has recently made the big discovery of an early attempt to construct syllogistic mnemonics, in a MS of the early 13th century. [...]
>
> This is a very primitive technique, but at least it shows that the highly developed terminology of [Peter of Spain](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peter-spain/) (who became Pope in 1276, under the name of John XXI; but see *footnote* : This can not have originated with him) had antecedents in Scholasticism itself.

See [*Summulae Logicales*, **Tractatus IV De Sillogismis**, §13 (page 64v)](https://books.google.it/books?id=re9OAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA64).

Thus the origin is probably unknown in the first half of 13th Century.

We found it "fully blown" into Petrus Hispanicus' standard textbook on logic, the *Tractatus*, called afterwards [Summule logicales](https://books.google.it/books?id=Qi8QAQAAIAAJ&pg=PR43); see [page 52](https://books.google.it/books?id=Qi8QAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA52).

Another source is [William of Sherwood](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/william-sherwood/)'s logical treatise [Introductiones in logicam](https://books.google.it/books?id=f3uMdwDVvL8C&pg=PA66), written in the middle of the 13th century.

Comment: In short, there's no known surviving document that would shed light on the author(s) of the vowel-consonant assignments? How to find the earliest published mention of Barbara, Celarent, Darii, and Ferio?

Comment: @אהרןרובין - published ? I've linked the intro to the modern edition with the discussion of medieval *manuscripts* of Peter's textbbok as well as medieval commentators. See [page c](https://books.google.it/books?id=Qi8QAQAAIAAJ&pg=PR43) : "The number of printed editions is tremendous. Their number seems to be not far from 200."